# Busca Palavra Chave Atribuir If e Else com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, javascript-eventos, algoritmo-de-busca

Olá pessoal estou tentando fazer uma seleção automatica de frete na minha loja, por que a plataforma loja integrada nao oferece opção de frete especificos para produtos, logo tenho: 
*Transportador: Apenas para Camisetas

Correios: Mascaras e Canecas*

Então queri localizar as palavras chaves "Camiseta" e "Mascara"; desta forma imprimir a mensagem avisando a forma de frete que tem disponivel, inabilitando a outra;

Fatos: So consegui localizar com document.indexOf e o IF e else nao funciona; /

```js
 
    function inicia() {    

   
   if (true) { 

         var nomeproduto=document.querySelector(".produto-info a").innerHTML
         
         var mask=nomeproduto.indexOf("Mascara");

          if (mask > 0) { 
            var firstfrete=document.querySelector(".formas-envio > ul > li:first-child");

            firstfrete.textContent = "Mascaras & Canecas somente por Correios!";
          } 

          else { alert("Frete Mascaras & Canecas Somente Correios"); }  
           } 

             else { alert("");} 
      
     

  if (true) { 
        
         
         var shirt=nomeproduto.indexOf("Camiseta");

          if (shirt > 0) {  

            var firstfrete=document.querySelector(".formas-envio > ul > li:last-child");

            firstfrete.textContent = "Camisetas exclusivamente Transportadora, Demais produtos apenas correios!";


          } 

          else { alert("Frete Camisetas Somente Transportadora"); }        

           } 

     else { alert("");}  

            }
    window.addEventListener("load",inicia);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.awsli.com.br/production/static/loja/estrutura/v1/css/all.min.css?v=42a13fc" type="text/css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.awsli.com.br/production/static/loja/estrutura/v1/css/bootstrap-responsive.css?v=42a13fc" type="text/css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.awsli.com.br/production/static/loja/estrutura/v1/css/style-responsive.css?v=42a13fc">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.imaginizesw.com.br/tema.css?v=20200613-165443">
      
      
<tbody style="padding: 40px;">
    <tr data-produto-id="45146859" data-produto-quantidade="2">
             
              <td class="sem-borda">
                <div class="produto-info">
                  
                   <a href="https://www.imaginizesw.com.br/camiseta-rick-and-morty-portal-gun-portal-dimensional-rick-and-morty-serie--" class="">
                    <h2>Mascara Rick and Morty Portal Gun - Portal Dimensional - Rick and Morty Serie</h2>
                  </a>                 
                 
<a href="https://www.imaginizesw.com.br/camiseta-rick-and-morty-portal-gun-portal-dimensional-rick-and-morty-serie--" class="">
                    <h2>Camiseta Rick and Morty Portal Gun - Portal Dimensional - Rick and Morty Serie</h2>
                  </a>  


                </div>
              </td>
              

  
    <div class="preco-produto destaque-preco ">
        
        
          
            
              <div>
                <s class="preco-venda titulo" style="font-family: Roboto;">
                  R$ 69,00
                </s>
                <strong class="preco-promocional cor-principal titulo" style="font-family: Roboto;">
                  R$ 59,00
                </strong>
              </div>
            
          
        
      
    </div>
  


                </td>
              
              <td class="clearfix">
                <form action="https://www.imaginizesw.com.br/carrinho/produto/45146859/atualizar" method="post">
                  <div class="quantidade">
                    <a href="https://www.imaginizesw.com.br/carrinho/produto/45146859/atualizar/1" class="icon-minus"></a>
                    <input type="text" class="input-mini" name="quantidade" value="2" autocomplete="off" style="font-family: Roboto;">
                    <a href="https://www.imaginizesw.com.br/carrinho/produto/45146859/atualizar/3" class="icon-plus"></a>
                    <button class="botao principal pequeno atualizar-quantidade" style="background-color: rgb(255, 215, 0); font-family: Roboto;">Atualizar quantidade</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </td>
              
                <td>
                  <div class="preco-produto">
                    <strong class="preco-promocional cor-principal titulo" style="font-family: Roboto;">
                      R$ 118,00
                    </strong>
                  </div>
                </td>
              
              <td>
                <div class="excluir">
                  <a href="https://www.imaginizesw.com.br/carrinho/produto/45146859/remover" class="icon-trash"></a>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          

          
            <tr class="hidden-phone bg-dark">
              <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
              
                <td colspan="2">
                  <div class="subtotal">
                    <span>Subtotal: </span>
                    <strong class="titulo cor-principal" data-subtotal-valor="118.0" style="font-family: Roboto;">
                      R$ 118,00
                    </strong>
                  </div>
                </td>
              
            </tr>
          

          
          
              </td>
              <td colspan="2">
 <div class="formas-envio">
                  <ul>
                    <li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="formaEnvio" value="195" data-valor="13.93" data-code="transportadora"><b class="prazo">10 dias úteis</b> <span class="cor-principal valor">R$ 13,93</span> <span class="nome">Transportadora</span></label></li><li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="formaEnvio" value="59360" data-valor="16.53" data-code="Correios-2"><b class="prazo">15 dias úteis</b> <span class="cor-principal valor">R$ 16,53</span> <span class="nome">Correios - SEDEX</span></label></li></ul>
                  
</div>







 <div id="preco-frete" style="display: block;">
<span class="texto">
Comprando mais <span id="falta">R$ 32.00</span> ganhe <span>FRETE GRÁTIS!!!</span>
</span>
</div></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

           
              </td>
            </tr>
          
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Qual a finalidade de `if (true)`?

Answer (score 0):

function inicia() {

```
const nomeproduto = document.querySelector(".produto-info a").innerHTML

// Como é trata a string como se fosse um array, 
// retorna a posição e -1 caso não encontre
if (nomeproduto.toLowerCase.indexOf("mascara") > -1) { 
    // Caso não funcione, precisa trocar para let,
    // porem acredito que funcione, pois o const só não permite que o objeto seja sobreescrito
    const firstfrete=document.querySelector(".formas-envio > ul > li:first-child");
    firstfrete.textContent = "Mascaras & Canecas somente por Correios!";
} else { 
    console.log("Frete Mascaras & Canecas Somente Correios"); 
}  
// Pelo exemplo, poderia fica no else anterior
if (nomeproduto.toLowerCase.indexOf("camiseta") > -1) { 
    const firstfrete=document.querySelector(".formas-envio > ul > li:last-child");
    firstfrete.textContent = "Camisetas exclusivamente Transportadora, Demais produtos apenas correios!";
} else {
    console.log("Frete Camisetas Somente Transportadora"); 
}
```

}

window.addEventListener("load",inicia);

```js
function inicia() {    

    const nomeproduto = document.querySelector(".produto-info a").innerHTML
    
    // Como é trata a string como se fosse um array, 
    // retorna a posição e -1 caso não encontre
    if (nomeproduto.toLowerCase.indexOf("mascara") > -1) { 
        // Caso não funcione, precisa trocar para let,
        // porem acredito que funcione, pois o const só não permite que o objeto seja sobreescrito
        const firstfrete=document.querySelector(".formas-envio > ul > li:first-child");
        firstfrete.textContent = "Mascaras & Canecas somente por Correios!";
    } else { 
        console.log("Frete Mascaras & Canecas Somente Correios"); 
    }  
    // Pelo exemplo, poderia fica no else anterior
    if (nomeproduto.toLowerCase.indexOf("camiseta") > -1) { 
        const firstfrete=document.querySelector(".formas-envio > ul > li:last-child");
        firstfrete.textContent = "Camisetas exclusivamente Transportadora, Demais produtos apenas correios!";
    } else {
        console.log("Frete Camisetas Somente Transportadora"); 
    }
}
   
window.addEventListener("load",inicia);
```

```js
function freteMascara(texto){
    // Como é trata a string como se fosse um array, 
    // retorna a posição e -1 caso não encontre
    if (texto.toLowerCase().indexOf("mascara") > -1) { 
        const mascara=document.querySelector(".formas-envio > ul > li:first-child");
        mascara.textContent = "Mascaras & Canecas somente por Correios!";
    }
}
function freteCamiseta(texto){
    // Como é trata a string como se fosse um array, 
    // retorna a posição e -1 caso não encontre
    if (texto.toLowerCase().indexOf("camiseta") > -1) { 
        const camiseta=document.querySelector(".formas-envio > ul > li:last-child");
        camiseta.textContent = "Camisetas exclusivamente Transportadora, Demais produtos apenas correios!";
    }
}

function inicia() {    
  // Como possui mais de uma tag a na classe produto-info
  // Estava apenas pegando o primeiro
  // Caso tenha sempre um, trocara para o querySelector e tirar o for
    const produtos = document.querySelectorAll(".produto-info a")
    for(const produto of produtos) {
        freteMascara(produto.innerHTML)
        freteCamiseta(produto.innerHTML)
    }
}
   
window.addEventListener("load",inicia);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.awsli.com.br/production/static/loja/estrutura/v1/css/all.min.css?v=42a13fc" type="text/css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.awsli.com.br/production/static/loja/estrutura/v1/css/bootstrap-responsive.css?v=42a13fc" type="text/css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.awsli.com.br/production/static/loja/estrutura/v1/css/style-responsive.css?v=42a13fc">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.imaginizesw.com.br/tema.css?v=20200613-165443">
      
      
<tbody style="padding: 40px;">
    <tr data-produto-id="45146859" data-produto-quantidade="2">
             
        <td class="sem-borda">
            <div class="produto-info">
                
                <a href="https://www.imaginizesw.com.br/camiseta-rick-and-morty-portal-gun-portal-dimensional-rick-and-morty-serie--" class="">
                    <h2>Mascara Rick and Morty Portal Gun - Portal Dimensional - Rick and Morty Serie</h2>
                </a>                 
                
                <a href="https://www.imaginizesw.com.br/camiseta-rick-and-morty-portal-gun-portal-dimensional-rick-and-morty-serie--" class="">
                    <h2>Camiseta Rick and Morty Portal Gun - Portal Dimensional - Rick and Morty Serie</h2>
                </a>  

            </div>
        </td>

        <!-- TD faltando -->
        <td>
            <div class="preco-produto destaque-preco ">
                <div>
                    <s class="preco-venda titulo" style="font-family: Roboto;">
                        R$ 69,00
                    </s>
                    <strong class="preco-promocional cor-principal titulo" style="font-family: Roboto;">
                        R$ 59,00
                    </strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
              
        <td class="clearfix">
            <form action="https://www.imaginizesw.com.br/carrinho/produto/45146859/atualizar" method="post">
                <div class="quantidade">
                    <a href="https://www.imaginizesw.com.br/carrinho/produto/45146859/atualizar/1" class="icon-minus"></a>
                    <input type="text" class="input-mini" name="quantidade" value="2" autocomplete="off" style="font-family: Roboto;">
                    <a href="https://www.imaginizesw.com.br/carrinho/produto/45146859/atualizar/3" class="icon-plus"></a>
                    <button class="botao principal pequeno atualizar-quantidade" style="background-color: rgb(255, 215, 0); font-family: Roboto;">Atualizar quantidade</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </td>
              
        <td>
            <div class="preco-produto">
            <strong class="preco-promocional cor-principal titulo" style="font-family: Roboto;">
                R$ 118,00
            </strong>
            </div>
        </td>
              
        <td>
            <div class="excluir">
                <a href="https://www.imaginizesw.com.br/carrinho/produto/45146859/remover" class="icon-trash"></a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
          
    <tr class="hidden-phone bg-dark">
        <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div class="subtotal">
                <span>Subtotal: </span>
                <strong class="titulo cor-principal" data-subtotal-valor="118.0" style="font-family: Roboto;">
                    R$ 118,00
                </strong>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
     <!-- fechando sobrando           </td>  -->
     <!-- faltando -->
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div class="formas-envio">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label class="radio">
                            <input type="radio" name="formaEnvio" value="195" data-valor="13.93" data-code="transportadora">
                            <b class="prazo">10 dias úteis</b> 
                            <span class="cor-principal valor">
                                R$ 13,93
                            </span> 
                            <span class="nome">Transportadora</span>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="radio">
                            <input type="radio" name="formaEnvio" value="59360" data-valor="16.53" data-code="Correios-2">
                            <b class="prazo">
                                15 dias úteis
                            </b> 
                            <span class="cor-principal valor">
                                R$ 16,53
                            </span> 
                            <span class="nome">Correios - SEDEX</span>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="preco-frete" style="display: block;">
                <span class="texto">
                Comprando mais <span id="falta">R$ 32.00</span> ganhe <span>FRETE GRÁTIS!!!</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        <!-- Sobrando </div> -->
        </td>
    </tr>

          <!-- sobrando 
              </td>
            </tr>
          --> 
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score -1):

O indexOf retorna a posição inicial do Texto procurado, se esse texto esta no começo da string ele vai retorna a posição 0, quando ele não encontra nada ele retorna -1.

No caso o if deve ficar da seguinte forma:

```
if(shirt != -1) {
 ...logica aqui
} else {
  ...
}
```